# Cannot get mapped map to return value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I can't figure out why this is returning undefined:

```
filterComms = (cards) => {
                    emptyArray = []
                    emptyArray[0] = cards
                    // console.log('emptyArray', emptyArray)
                    emptyArray.map(
                        (v, i) => {
                            return(
                                v.comment.map(
                                    (c, i) => {
                                        if (c.parent_comment_id === null) {
                                            console.log(c) 
                                            return c
                                        }
                                    }
                                )
                            )
                        }
                    )
                }
```

When I console.log `c`, I receive the correct value.

This is what the data looks like that I've fed in: https://codepen.io/schoenbl/pen/JgdOQN?editors=0010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not returning the mapped value - in fact, because you aren't assigning anything to the new array returned from `map` (it doesn't mutate the original array), that entire `map` function is useless because the result isn't being assigned to anything, as such it's being garbage-collected. The simplest fix is to `return` the `map`.

```
return emptyArray.map(...);
```

If you were trying to use the ES6 implicit return in arrow functions, that requires the first non-whitespace character after the fat arrow `=>` to *not* be an opening curly brace `{`. Your function can easily be simplified like so, especially because you're basically making a new array - you don't even need the `emptyArray` variable. You can also mix in some destructuring to only get the wanted properties back:

```
filterComms = cards => [cards].map(({ comment }) => comment.map(({ parent_comment_id, ...c }) => parent_comment_id === null ? { ...c, parent_comment_id } : undefined));
```